# Jooq generate class for view

Tags: java, psql, jooq

is possible to generate class for view in Jooq? Or how can I work with view in Jooq? I saw question about generating DAOs for views but this not solve my problem. Simple, I created view in Psql db, and now I want to work with this view in java. My config file looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
    <jdbc>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5784/test</url>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>pass</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <inputSchema>tp0</inputSchema>

            <excludes>
                .*_y201[0-9]m.{2}|
                .*_y1970m.{2}|
                .*_y2000m.{2}|
                .*_y2009m.{2}|
                .*_y2009M.{2}
            </excludes>
        </database>

        <generate>
            <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        </generate>
        <target>
            <packageName>com.testapp.model.generated</packageName>
            <directory>/home/user/dev/projects/core/src/main/java</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Thank You for any help!

Comment: What is your formal view definition? Is it in the `tp0` schema? Can your `user` select from it? (Btw: probably not relevant for this question, but you have duplicate `<excludes/>` configurations)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. There were mistake in jdbc definition